# How do I find the first and last number in a randomly generated number line?

Tags: java

I have this program I need to make where I make a line of 10 numbers that are randomly generated, I need to find the largest, smallest, first, and last numbers on the line. I already have the number line and I found the largest and smallest number. I need help figuring out how to find the first and last numbers on the line. Here is the code I have so far:

```
// variables
    Random generator = new Random();
    int max = 0, min = 100, random, first, last;

    // for
    System.out.println("Here are 10 random numbers: \n");
    for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {

        // get random number and output
        random = 1 + generator.nextInt(100);
        System.out.print(random + " ");

        // Max number
        if (random > max)
            max = random;

        // Min number
        if (random < min)
            min = random;
    }

    // output
    System.out.print("\n\nThe first number is " + last);
    System.out.print("\nThe last number is " + first);
    System.out.println("\nThe largest random number is " + max);
    System.out.print("The smallest random number is " + min);
```

Comment: First and last should be even easier than min/max given that you have bounds for `count` as well: `if( count == 1) { /*first*/ } if( count == 10) { /*last*/ }`

Comment: Hint: ... or use a flag ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) are very good tools to store Objects and apply some algorithms on them.

try this:

```
Random generator = new Random();
final int MIN = 0, MAX = 100;
LinkedList<Integer> numberLine = new LinkedList<>();

for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {
    int random = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
    numberLine.add(random);
}

int last = numberLine.getLast();
int first = numberLine.getFirst();
int max = Collections.max(numberLine);
int min = Collections.min(numberLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to take special cases out of the loop if possible. It definitely is possible here:

```
// variables
Random generator = new Random();
int max = 0, min = 100, random, first, last;

public FirstAndLast() {
    // for
    System.out.println("Here are 10 random numbers: \n");
    first = nextRandomNumber();
    for (int count = 2; count <= 9; count++) {
        nextRandomNumber();
    }
    last = nextRandomNumber();

    // output
    System.out.print("\n\nThe first number is " + first);
    System.out.print("\nThe last number is " + last);
    System.out.println("\nThe largest random number is " + max);
    System.out.println("The smallest random number is " + min);
}

private int nextRandomNumber() {
    // get random number and output
    random = 1 + generator.nextInt(100);
    System.out.print(random + " ");

    // Max number
    if (random > max)
        max = random;

    // Min number
    if (random < min)
        min = random;

    return random;
}
```

I introduced an auxiliary method to do the work with each number.

BTW, you seemed to have swapped `first` and `last` in your output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomGenerated {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variables
        Random generator = new Random();
        int max = 0, min = 100, random, first = 0, last = 0;

        // for
        System.out.println("Here are 10 random numbers: \n");
        for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {

            // get random number and output
            random = 1 + generator.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(random + " ");

            // last
            if (count == 10) {
                last = random;
            }

            // first
            if (count == 1) {
                first = random;
            }

            // Max number
            if (random > max)
                max = random;

            // Min number
            if (random < min)
                min = random;
        }

        // output
        System.out.print("\n\nThe first number is " + first);
        System.out.print("\nThe last number is " + last);
        System.out.println("\nThe largest random number is " + max);
        System.out.print("The smallest random number is " + min);
    }

}
```